# Nosetests missing command line option

Tags: python, nose

Using nose 1.3.7 and documentation lists following command line option

> **--xunit-prefix-with-testsuite-name** Whether to prefix the class name under test with testsuite name. Defaults to false.

Documentation is available on:
https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

But when trying to use it I get error:

> nosetests: error: no such option: --xunit-prefix-with-testsuite-name

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some research i noticed its not in the 1.3.7 release of nose.

if you look at their github repo that option was added Nov 2015.

https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/commits/master/nose/plugins/xunit.py

if you look at their releases you will see the 1.3.7 was released earlier in June that year.

https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/releases/tag/release_1.3.7

I noticed that the option is enabled when you do

```
nosetests --with-xunit --xunit-testsuite-name=MYTESTSUITE
```